# How to use $count aggregation operator(or workaround) in MongoDB 2.2?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, version

I got 2 mongodb aggregation querys which worked fine until I needed to downgrade my mongodb version to 2.2 because it needs to run on a raspberry pi 4 (2.2 is the newest version working on a pi 4).

Now it just throws the Error:

```
MongoError: Exception: unrecognized pipeline stage name '$count'
```

The aggregation querys:

```
msg_count_per_id: [{$match: {}}, {$group: {_id: "$id", count:{$sum:1}}}],
id_count_distinct: [{$group: {_id: '$id'}}, {$group: {_id: 'distinct_count', count: {$sum: 1}}}]
```

I already read that I need to have MongoDB v3.4 to get the count stage working, but I cannot use another version of MongoDB.

Now my question is, is there any workaround to get this aggregation querys working for MongoDB v2.2? Or do I need to solve this without aggregations?

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: Can you post your query / expected result? `The $count stage is equivalent to the following $group + $project sequence:`[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/)